# How can I use tkinter to make a user input a message that gets sent via a webhook to multiple chat rooms?

Tags: python, tkinter, webhooks

I built a .exe program that I can use to send a message to multiple chat rooms at work quickly via a webhook. However, if I want to edit the message, I would have to edit the message in the python script itself. Which I don't mind as it doesn't take me long but if I'm off from work and another manager is covering, who doesn't know Python, I would like to be able to allow them the functionality to just input the message in an  interface which then gets sent to all the chat rooms via the webhooks. Anyone know if tkinter would be the best package or is there something else?

Thank you in advance!

Looked into tkinter (still fairly new to the package) and trying to build something on my own but not sure where to start in terms of linking it to my python script with the webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

umm i guess

```
import tkinter.simpledialog as dlg

s = dlg.askstring(title="Get String", prompt="Enter New String")
print(s)
save_or_send_or_whatever(s)
```